# How we can set the memory and CPU resources limits with spark operators?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, operators, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

i'm new in spark-operator i'm confused how to setup the resources request and limits in YAML file for example in my case i have request 512m of memory for driver pod, but what about limits, it is unbounded ?

```html
spec:
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: 200m
    memory: 512m
    labels:
      version: 2.4.5
    serviceAccount: spark
```

spec:
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: 200m
    memory: 512m
    labels:
      version: 2.4.5
    serviceAccount: spark

Answer (score 4):

It is good practice to set limits when defining your yaml file. If you do not do so you run the risk of using all resources on node as per this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#if-you-do-not-specify-a-memory-limit) since there is no upper bound.

---

Memory limits for the driver and executor pods are set internally by the Kubernetes scheduler backend in Spark, and calculated as the value of spark.{driver|executor}.memory + memory overhead.

Comment: yes, i know how it work in kubernetes,  but i'm talking about spark operator which uses YAML file to deploy spark Application

Comment: Try to post your question [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues) also